# Why "requireSSL='true'" was throwing IIS error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, iis-7, web-config, tls1.2

I am working on MVC framework in ASP.NET where, I was trying to access the application but I was not able to go past the login screen, after which it kept throwing the not found IIS error. After workaround i found that i had this line : `httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"` in my `web.config` file which was stopping the access. Can anyone help me understand the problem and concept here?
Thanks already.

I was able to access the site after removing the requireSSL part only.

Web-config

```
httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"
```

Global.asax's Application Start :

```
if (ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol.HasFlag(SecurityProtocolType.Tls12) == false)
{
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
      ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
}
```

I think the part of code in `global.asax`'s Application Start might be causing the problem, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Have you written [RequireHttps] on your login method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Websites use cookies to store information between page requests or browsing sessions.

The callback from an external provider to your site contains security tokens(`httpCookies`) that allow access to your site and contain user information.

If someone manage to steal other's authentication cookie for a website, he  could carry out all the actions that they are capable of.

Transmitting this information over HTTPS to prevent interception while this information travels over the Internet is important

You can stop script access to all cookies in your site by adding a simple flag: HttpOnly. You can set
this flag in the web.config, as follows:

```
<httpCookies domain="" httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
```

So If you write `requireSSL="true"` in your `Web.config` It Enforcing the external provider to make their callbacks to your site using `HTTPS` only.

@Vishesh Pandita In your case you are trying to access site using HTTP only. So faced "HTTP Error 403 - 403.4 Forbidden: SSL required" error.It means the page you are trying to access is secured with Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

Solution:
To view the page, you must enable SSL (Secure Sockets Layer) by typing "https://" instead of "http://" at the beginning of the address you are attempting to reach. The "s" in "https" specifies a secure site.

[Migration for HTTP to HTTPs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6073543?hl=en)

source : [Professional ASP.NET MVC 5](https://www.amazon.in/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-Jon-Galloway-ebook/dp/B00LVVUISG?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=kindlecontentin24-21&ascsubtag=_k_EAIaIQobChMI9uThtcOf4gIVGIrICh3Y7gn8EAQYASABEgIoE_D_BwE_k_)

Comment: Thanks a lot @mannan for the answer. But why was it not working in my case. What was going wrong? I actually wanted this ' Enforcing the external provider to make their callbacks to your site using HTTPS only.'

Comment: You must obtain a security certificate for enabling HTTPS for your site. in your case you are accessing site using http only